# Service timer webservice set/get data

Tags: java, android

I need to send the current coordinates with the webservice. All of this is to take place automatically, 55 seconds. I want to make this a separate thread. It can not be assigned to one activity at a moment because the program makes changes to the current activity (by intent). So I want to send data topic was spontaneous and independent.

The second problem is that every 30 seconds I want to retrieve data via webservice and forwarding them to one class but not a problem, instances have already done.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Application;

public class Class1 extends Application {   
    private static Class1 instance;

public static synchronized Class1 getInstance(){
        if(instance==null){
          instance=new Class1();
        }
        return instance;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for CountDownTimer , if you want timer base service responses.Call your asynctask or your service class implementation inside timer's onTick method.

see demo from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html to know how to use countdowntimer.